# What is Code compiled unit in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to know what is code compiled unit in .net. It s located in this 
path C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\App_folders

I need to know why its created ccu file also an complied file with application extension dll.

Do this take any reference from here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the article at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163496.aspx

"By default, when you compile a Web application the compiled code is placed in the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder. This folder is a subdirectory of the location where you installed the .NET framework. Typically, the location is the following %FrameworkInstallLocation%\Temporary ASP.NET Files". 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx

"CCU stands for Code Compile Unit and refers to the CodeDOM tree created to generate the source code for the dynamic page class. The CCU file is a binary file that contains the serialized version of the CodeDOM tree for the page. "

"The CCU file maintains an up-to-date copy of the CodeDOM structure of the page ready to service these requests."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163496.aspx